# Автоматически перезагружать файлы при изменении их извне. Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

Постоянно появляются подобные сообщения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно ли настроить vs так, чтобы при изменении извне файлы всегда перезагружались без подтверждения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зайдите в меню <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd>, в разделе <kbd>Environment</kbd> > <kbd>Documents</kbd> поставьте галку возле пункта <kbd>Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes</kbd>. При первом изменении студия все равно отобразит диалог, но там будет дополнительная опция.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]